# QUnit Data Provider

Tags: javascript, phpunit, qunit

We have the concept of data provider in PHPUnit . Data provider method provide arbitrary arguments. Like below

```
<code>

<?php
class DataTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
/**
* @dataProvider provider
*/
public function testAdd($a, $b, $c)
{
   $this->assertEquals($c, $a + $b);
}

public function provider()
{
    return array(
      array(0, 0, 0),
      array(0, 1, 1),
      array(1, 0, 1),
      array(1, 1, 3)
   );
}
}
?>
</code>
```

Now my question is that how i can do this for Qunit ????

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is QUnit addon to run parameterized tests: https://github.com/AStepaniuk/qunit-parameterize

I think that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Wow Thanks a lot Alexander Stepaniuk